# Can i convert BAR ( Tidex ) to XRP ( Binance ) ?

Tags: wallet, exchanges, altcoin, ripple, trading

I need some advice, I do have some BARS with me on Tidex but I would like to send them to my Binance account but in other coin format e.g BARS to Ripple. Is it possible to do so, if any option please do let me know.

Answer (score 1):

So you want to;

1. Sell your BAR into another currency?
2. Send the new currency from Tidex to Binance?
3. Enter a new currency that is not BAR?

It will be easiest to sell BAR for ETH or BTC, since these make the biggest markets on Binance. Then send to Binance as you have the choice to buy many different coins from there.

What currency do you want to enter into after you have sold BAR?